# What is the most performant way to share a state via react context when we display a big number of components subscribed to it

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm building a small sample webshop application and I'm implementing a fare common use case.

I have a list of products and a basket.
The Cart component shows the current items int he basket and it has a button to empty the whole basket.
Each product has a button to add that specific item to the basket.

Since the products and the cart are in different components I decided to create a CartContext in order to share the Cart state and its methods to add an item and to empty the whole cart.

What I experience is that when I add any item to the basket, as per design, every component subscribed to the context gets re-rendered. This means the Cart component and each of the Product components.

Since in the Product component I don't need the basket current value but only the function to add the current item I'm looking if it is possible to share the addItem function without causing a re-render of each Product component due to the context update.

I have recreated a sample app here. https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-torvalds-t1hgc

Doing my research I found that one option could be to use useMemo and useCallback to memoize a function or an object, but since these functions are not pure I get strange results. EG, add a couple of items, then empty the basket, then try to add a new item and the previous items are still there. (Issue can be reproduce swapping comments in line 44-45 in cart.context.js)

I want to remove the extra re-render since I noticed that with a big number of products (EG. 100) the application works pretty fast on laptops and newer phones but it is laggy on some older hardware.
I could also solve this performance issue perhaps limiting the number of products rendered on screen using a library like react-infinite-scroll-component but I'm still interested to know whether I could avoid this re-render in other ways.

Thanks upfront for any suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same without needing to use useCallback or useMemo.

https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-leakey-pyjsw - my fork of your code

Though the way I've done this is a bit cheeky by having state updater function from the hook do conditional logic, I'm expecting someone to tell me off so watch this space ... but until then

Simple things we can fix

- **keys** using `index` should be a last resort really if ever.. essentially make it unique. ideally an `id`, but in your example `product.name` is the only unique thing, so when mapping, let's use that.
- 2 different lists can have the same keys, so don't worry about having `product.name` as a key in 2 lists, the **key** has to only be unique for each individual list.

Your example of useMemo, you're trying to memoize addItem without a dependency, `useMemo(()= > {}, [])`, so addItem will run once and have stale data, to fix this add `[cart]` as a dependency since you're relying on data, **but** as you might guess you're back where you started.

the state changes and useMemo/useCalback just gets overwritten.

- it also  **makes performance** worse as you are now using more memory to store the same data in useMemo case.

**what's another way of reading state .. or better yet  do you have access to previous state ?**

- Think back to your days of `class Components` and how we used setState.
- your addItem doesn't need to look into `cart` directly, it can use prevState.cart.items to check and update state.

There's other issues but, those are my main concerns, think about **what functions actually need state and how can you provide it** without cross-pollinating your 2 separate contexts and **keys.. keys are massive!**